# Detect specific keystroke in Powershell

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

I'm writing a program to automatically shut off a charger when my battery gets to 80%, but I'd like to have an override keyboard shortcut.

I'm using Powershell to make interfacing with the Arduino that shuts off my remote outlet easier, and I've got almost all of the coding working, I just can't seem to find a way to get Powershell to monitor for a specific combination of keystrokes (for example cntrl + alt + c) and then simply turn the charger on and ignore the rest. Basically, I'm just wondering if there is a way to have a variable remain false until I enter  a specific keystroke (even if working in a different window in the best case), and then change its value to true. I currently have the program checking charge level every five minutes, so I was thinking that I could also check the value of said variable before moving on at each interval.

If not, is there a way to accomplish the same sort of switch so that if you type  a value into the console at any time the variable will change values, but still have the rest of the code running while the program is listening for that input?

Thanks

Comment: Capturing keyboard input in powershell will only work as long as powershell has the focus

Comment: have a look at this great module made by a microsoft employee :[PSReadline](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for low level keyboard hooking in [C# here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx). You should be able to plagiarize / convert / modify this example for your own use.

The basic idea is that you need to hook into unmanaged code to do this across all processes. You'll need to use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of your app, pass this handle into [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register a callback, [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pass the hook up the chain, and [UnhookWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove it when you are done. Inside of your callback you will be able to evaluate the parameters to determine if the key you are looking for has been pressed. There are lots of examples of making calls from [Powershell into the WinAPI](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Demo-of-calling-C-and-6ef0cd2b).

Comment: Plesse include the main points of the link in your answer. Otherwise it will become invalid if the link goes down